# Rails - Creating a UID for a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model PhotoAlbum.

I'd like Rails to magically create a UID for PhotoAlbum when it's created. Preferably a very long digit/alphanumeric UID as if a bad guy had this UID they could do bad things.

Suggestions on:

- What to use to make the UID
- Where to assign the UID, can I do it in the schema as a default value? Or in the model as before or maybe after create? What's the smart way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple hex key? Just take a combination of pseudo random data and model data and feed it into hexdigest to get a nice fairly unique key, a simple check can make sure it's really unique.

```
class Album
  before_create :set_uid

  protected
    def set_uid
      # This only works before_create obviously, otherwise it would
      # find itself and loop eternally.
      while self.uid.blank? or !Album.find_by_uid(self.uid).blank?
        self.uid = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{self.title}--#{Time.current.usec}--")
      end
    end
end
```

You could probably clean that up a bit but it should work.

As for doing it in the schema, I would guess that depends on what database engine you're using, I'm no expert there ;)

Comment: I'd not use that - but then I'm paranoid about security. If the source code is ever released to the wild, hackers could guess the UID for any object with a small amount of testing. They could simply try every usec combination around the time the entry was created.

Comment: Or... if someone copies-and-pastes your example directly, attackers don't even need leaked source code, they have yours. Assuming they have the title, and since Time.current.usec only returns a number up to 999999, they only need to check 999999 possibilities before they have the "secret"

Comment: And for even more fun: let's assume that this is actually for a reasonably sized service - where hundreds of thousands of albums are created. Eventually Time.current.usec is going to return the same number. If the title of the album is the same, and the usec value is the same, it means that the uid value is going to be the same for two albums. That's not so far-fetched if the Original Poster were to create a common default album name, or if people used something like "My Party" as their album name. Look up the "birthday paradox" and try out http://jeff.aaron.ca/cgi-bin/birthday

Comment: First of all, that's why we build in the check and regenerate the UID if it already exists. If we go by the assumption that this the sole authentication for a massive public service then you're probably right but I use this sort of validation frequently for cases where formal user accounts would be far too complex, like unsubscriptions, giving people "one time passes" to view a page or similar. Not everything demands top level security. That's not to say it shouldn't be considered but it also doesn't mean this is not a valid technique for certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

Rails handles database IDs for you by default.

You really shouldn't be using security by obscurity, though-- you should be using plugins to handle authentication and authorization, and then the bad guys won't be able to do anything even IF they know the ID.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an after_initialize hook?

I'm working on the assumption that you don't want the UUID as your primary key (otherwise things are more complicated). I'd avoid that for your purposes.

I'm doing all of this without testing, unfortunately, so I can't be 100% sure that I've not made any typos. If you encounter any problems, feel free to message me.

Firstly, you'll need to add uuidtools to your project. Assuming rails 2, this is in config/environment.rb

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ..
  # You can try a later uuidtools version, but this is the one I've worked with
  config.gem "uuidtools", :version => '2.1.1'
  ..
end
```

Once you've added the above, run "sudo rake gems:install" and it should download and install the gem.

Then, in your model, add this code:

```
  validates_length_of :uuid, :is => 36 # Untested.. makes sense to me though
  def after_initialize
    self.uuid ||= UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
  end
```

And in your migration for creating the table:

```
create table :photo_albums do |t|
  ..
  t.string :id, :limit => 36
  ..
end
```

I hope that helps.

Oskar